# C# .Net where condition

Tags: c#, .net, linq

I have this code to select the city for each person whose Id matches from the list of cities:

```
  public List<PersonelDto> MapPersonelDto(List<Personel> personels,List<City> cities)
    {
        var result = new List<PersonelDto>();

        foreach (var item in personels)
        {
            var personel = new PersonelDto
            {
                Id = item.Id,
                Maaş = item.Salary,
                MedeniHal = item.MartialStatus,
                Meslek = item.Job,
                Soyisim = item.LastName,
                Şehir = (from s in cities where s.Id == item.CityId select s.name).ToString()

            };
            result.Add(personel);

            
        }

        return result;


    }
```

But City's value come out like this:

> System.Linq.Enumerable+WhereSelectListIterator`2[Personnel_Registration.City,System.String]

How can I fix this?

Comment: So many lists when a bare enumerable would be faster and use less ram.

Comment: foreach hehe xd

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 from s in cities where s.Id == item.CityId select s.name
```

return an IEnumerable - there might be more than one city

do instead

```
Şehir = (from s in cities where s.Id == item.CityId select s.name).FirstOrDefault().ToString()
```

which selects the first element

Note that this assumes that there is always a matching city. If not then you should supply a default value

```
   Şehir = (from s in cities where s.Id == item.CityId select s.name).FirstOrDefault("unknow city").ToString()
```

Answer (score 1):

The error is because there's nothing in the type system metadata to guarantee you won't have more than one city match, and so the result of the expression is a potential **collection** of 0, 1, or more cities. What you see is the result of calling `.ToString()` on that collection.

To fix it, you can do this:

```
public IEnumerable<PersonelDto> MapPersonelDto(IEnumerable<Personel> personels, IEnumerable<City> cities)
{
    return personels.Select( p => {
            new PersonelDto() {
                Id = item.Id,
                Maaş = item.Salary,
                MedeniHal = item.MartialStatus,
                Meslek = item.Job,
                Soyisim = item.LastName,
                Şehir = string.Join(",", cities.Where(c => c.Id == p.CityId).Select(c=> c.name));
            }
        });
}
```

Or, if you're confident you only want one city, you could do this:

```
public IEnumerable<PersonelDto> MapPersonelDto(IEnumerable<Personel> personels, IEnumerable<City> cities)
{
    return personels.Select( p => {
            new PersonelDto() {
                Id = item.Id,
                Maaş = item.Salary,
                MedeniHal = item.MartialStatus,
                Meslek = item.Job,
                Soyisim = item.LastName,
                Şehir = cities.FirstOrDefault(c => c.Id == p.CityId)?.name;
            }
        });
}
```

---

Note the complete lack of Lists. You **really** ought to get out of the habit of using `List<T>` everywhere, and instead let things remain as an `IEnumerable<T>` as much as possible. This can make your code faster and MUCH more efficient with RAM use.

Another benefit is it makes your code more flexible. For example, *you can still pass the existing Lists to this new method*. And if for some reason you need the result to be a `List<>` for the next method call (hint: you probably don't really need this at all) you can always add a `.ToList()` after calling the method. But, again, don't do that unless you really have to!